# what $D_8/D_8$ is isomorphic to

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is $D_8/D_8$ isomorphic to? Why $\,1\,?\,$

By definition, I think it should be $D_8$, since $\,D_8/D_8=\{gD_8|g\in D_8\}=D_8$.

$(D_8/D_8:\;$  the quotient group of $D_8$ by itself.)

Comment: $\{D_8\}$ is a set with only one element, and $D_8$ is different from $\{D_8\}$.

Comment: I find it strange that none of the answers have mentioned that quotient groups effectively shrink/collapse/identify elements of groups. All of the fancy terminology (Coset, normal subgroup, quotient, etc...) hides that very simple and important fact.

Comment: @TylerBailey: You can add your own answer if you find the existing ones lacking, you know.

Comment: I tried my best, let me know if it is incomprehensible or overly wordy! :p

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very too old and very elementary

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: note that $$\left|\dfrac {D_8}{D_8}\right| = \left|D_8/D_8\right| = 1$$

What does that tell you with respect to what that one-element *group* $D_8/D_8$ must be?
 And why, then, it must be isomorphic to the trivial group?

Try to better understand how "cosets" are defined and how *quotient group* is defined and how these *relate*, but also how they differ.

Answer (score 21):

The process of quotienting out a normal subgroup is just a fancy way of shrinking down the group we are working with. I'll try to give a non-technical answer because you seem bogged down by the details at the moment without an idea of what is actually happening:

Say you have a group $G$ and some (normal) subgroup $Q$. You don't want to deal with $G$ all by itself, it is too complicated. You decide to take ALL of the elements of $Q$ and consider them to be "the same." That is the quotient subgroup $G/Q$.

For your example, $D_8$: You decide to quotient by $D_8$, which  means you are going to start considering any element I decide to give you to be all the same element. Then you're left with a group that only has $1$ element! It has to be the trivial group.

For another example, look at $\mathbb{Z} = \{...,-1, 0, 1, 2, ...\}$ and $2\mathbb{Z} = \{... ,-2, 0, 2, 4, ...\}$. We decide to quotient by $2\mathbb{Z}$. What do you think will happen? Well, we end up calling all of the EVEN elements one thing (we call evens $0$ since they have a nice property that $\mathrm{ E + E = E}$ and $\mathrm{ E + O = O}$ ), and all of the ODD elements another (call it $1$). All odd numbers are just an even number plus one anyway, right? So now we're down to a group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with two elements.

Comment: _very_ nice explanation

Comment: I always appreciate the more wordy answers!

Comment: I think this is the way to do it, and as a bonus lets you see why normal subgroups are the ones you can quotient by. (They are kernels of "let's keep this the same" homomorphisms). I wrote a [blog post](http://reallyeli.com/posts/normal_subgroups_hold_things_constant.html) about it!

Answer (score 12):

$G/G$ is the set of cosets of $G$ in itself under the operation of coset mulitplication.  The quotient $G/G$ is the one element set $\{G\}$ with the operation of coset multiplication, and therefore isomorphic to the trivial group.

Answer (score 10):

The error is that $\{ g D_8 | g \in D_8 \} = \{ D_8 \} \ne D_8$.

This follows from the fact that $1 D_8 = D_8$.  All cosets are the same size as $D_8$ and subsets of $D_8$, so by the pidgeonhole principle, they must be equal.

But notice that $1 D_8 \in D_8 / D_8$.  It is not equal to it.

Answer (score 7):

$G/G$ is always equal to $1$. This is because the quotient group is the structure of the equivalency classes of cosets, not the cosets themselves. This is a group because we can inherit a group structure from $G$. So $D_8/D_8$ is a group of the cosets of $D_8$. There is only one of these.